# ZAP security tool is very time consuming

Tags: security, testing, zap

I have run ZAP security tool for Test .net MVC application, ZAP tool takes too much time to run script and sometimes tool not responding well. Is there any other tool which gives me accurate results like zap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this blog post about speeding up ZAP scans: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQscanSpeed

You can also ask specific questions on the ZAP User Group: http://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

We'll do our best to help, but its difficult unless we have some more info ;)

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)